# ViewPager with setCurrentItem(position, false) but with fade-in transition?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, transition, fade

I am trying to use the AHBottomNavigation (https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation) and I am following its demo app for make my own.

In the demo app it uses ViewPager and FragmentPagerAdapter to change between fragments, and everything is working perfectly.

My problem is, I want to add a fade-in fade-out transition between the fragments, I had tried to change this:

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(position, false);
```

for

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
```

And I had added this in my MainActivity:

```
viewPager.setPageTransformer(false, new FadePageTransformer());

...

public class FadePageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {
    public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
        view.setTranslationX(view.getWidth() * -position);

        if(position <= -1.0F || position >= 1.0F) {
            view.setAlpha(0.0F);
        } else if( position == 0.0F ) {
            view.setAlpha(1.0F);
        } else {
            // position is between -1.0F & 0.0F OR 0.0F & 1.0F
            view.setAlpha(1.0F - Math.abs(position));
        }
    }
}
```

It actually works, but if I want to go from the first fragment to the last one, it shows all the fragments between them, like a scroll view.

It has a method in the Fragment class (DemoFragment) that I think I can use for a fade-in fade-out transition, but I have no idea of how to implement it, this is the method:

```
/**
 * Called when a fragment will be displayed
 */
public void willBeDisplayed() {
    // Do what you want here, for example animate the content
}
```

Sorry, I am new in android, I still learning, and I hope you can help me, thanks!

**UPDATE:**

I want to add a cross-fade animation between the fragments, like the example in Material Design (https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/bottom-navigation.html#bottom-navigation-behavior)

> Transition between active and inactive views using a cross-fade
>   animation.

Answer (score 1):

Since viewpagers transition through the pages inbetween, its animated page change should not be used according to the material design guidelines. Instead, you should use `setCurrentItem(int, boolean)` with the boolean parameter as false (this removes the transition through the inbetween elements) and perform the animation inside onTabSelected:

```
private Animation fadeOut;
private Animation fadeIn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    fadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_out);
    fadeOut.setDuration(150);
    fadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_in);
    fadeIn.setDuration(150);
    ...

    bottomNavigation.setOnTabSelectedListener(new AHBottomNavigation.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTabSelected(int position, boolean wasSelected) {
                if(!wasSelected) {
                    Fragment oldFrag = getCurrentFragment();
                    if(oldFrag.getView() != null) {
                        oldFrag.getView().startAnimation(fadeOut);
                    }

                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position, false);

                    // The following line might not be necessary
                    getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();

                    Fragment newFrag = getCurrentFragment();
                    if(newFrag.getView() != null) {
                        newFrag.getView().startAnimation(fadeIn);
                    }
                } else {
                    getCurrentFragment().onReopen();
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
}
```